# django-bootstrap-datepicker-plusを利用したいがエラーが起きてしまい実装できない

Tags: python, django

この状態でrunserverを立ち上げようとするとエラーが起こってしまいます。解決策などありましたらよろしくお願いします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
AttributeError: module 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus' has no attribute 'DatePickerInput'
```

**ソースコード:**

models.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Account
import bootstrap_datepicker_plus as datetimepicker
# フォームクラス作成
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # パスワード入力：非表示対応
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),label="パスワード")

    class Meta():
        # ユーザー認証
        model = User
        # フィールド指定
        fields = ('username','email','password')
        # フィールド名指定
        labels = {'username':"ユーザーID",'email':"メール"}

class AddAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        # モデルクラスを指定
        model = Account
        fields = ('last_name','first_name','year')
        labels = {'last_name':"苗字",'first_name':"名前",'year':'誕生日'}

        widgets = {
            'year': datetimepicker.DatePickerInput(
                format = '%Y-%m-%d',
                options = {
                    locale : 'ja',
                    dayViewHeaderFormat : 'YYYY年　MMMM',
                }
            ),
        }
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_bootstrap5',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus` は使ったことはありませんが、[公式のサイト](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/)を見る限り、

```py
import bootstrap_datepicker_plus as datetimepicker
```

ではなく、

```py
import bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets as datetimepicker
```

のような気がしますが、いかがですか。
一応、[こんな記事](https://pyming.info/2023/01/13/django-bootstrap_datepicker_plus_error/)のあるようですし。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決することができました。